# How to create multiple list programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-xml

I need to create multiple lists and each list should be in collapse view as shown in pic below

[image]

User can open multiple collapse section at a time.
I have to create this but I am not sure how I can do that, any hint or help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

> A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling two-level list. This
> differs from the ListView by allowing two levels: groups which can
> individually be expanded to show its children. The items come from the
> ExpandableListAdapter associated with this view.

Comment: thanks for pointing out in right direction....followed this tutorial to achieve the required result  `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-expandable-listview-using-kotlin`